# Portable duplicate file finder for Windows that makes it easy to add/remove folders to search

Tags: windows, file-management, file-search, duplicate-files, dark-theme

I am seeking recommendations for a duplicate file finder for Windows with the following features:

1. Portable (no writing to registry or outside of its own folder)
2. Easy to add/remove folders and subfolders that will be searched without having to manually type in every folder name
3. Shows date/time and folder for each result
4. Can delete specific duplicate files from the results within the application
5. No false-positives
6. Works well with an OS dark theme.
7. Gratis

I tried [AllDup](https://www.allsync.biz/alldup_help/alldup.php), but it failed for requirement #6.

I also tried the duplicate file finder in [FreeCommander](https://freecommander.com/), but it failed for requirements #2 and #6.

Open-source is preferred, but not required.  A simple binary comparison is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I use [CloneSpy](https://clonespy.en.softonic.com/).

Besides lack of dark mode, it ticks the rest of your requirements so would be worth a look.

You can set it to prompt (like the pic below), or just delete all duplicate files without confirmation.

[image]

Comment: Thanks KERR.  I think the lack of compatibility with dark theme may be a deal-breaker on that one.  The various "Search for" options look appealing though.